# How to send all traffic to a certain path with a application gateway (azure)

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-traffic-manager

I'm struggling to find a way of sending all traffic into a app gw to a certain website path.

Say my website is, stackoverflow.devops.com.

I have a App Service backend with the domain stackoverflow.devops.com.

The idea going forwards is to send all traffic to that website to a traffic manager, doing geolocation routing. Currently, if you're in Europe, it routes to an application gateway where the path is fine, and this works.

If you're in the states, it routes to a different application gateway (with the same backend pool) and I want to change the url to stackoverflow.devops.com/us for any traffic going through this app gw.

I've tried URL rewrites but getting a 'too many redirects' error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are redirecting back to the public DNS name and going back out to Traffic Manager which is creating a loop.

You should be able to specify '/us' as the URL path value on your rewrite rule.

I'm curious about what you are trying to achieve here though if the backend pool is the same for both application gateways.  Would you not want to have another App Service in the US region also?